# Probability that the mean of k observations out of N is under a certain value

Tags: r, math, probability

I'm trying to estimate the probability that the mean of 3 observations from a population is under a certain value.

Let's say I want to know what's the probability that the mean of 3 people's heights is under 1.8m

Population = c(1.7, 1.9, 1.6, 1.76, 1.8, 1.72, 1.99, 2, 1.66, 1.89)

If I pick randomly 3 observations (x_i, x_j, x_k)... What's the probability that the mean of these 3 observations is under 1.8m?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want the empirical probability based on your observations, or the theoretical probability based on a hypothesised (or known) population density?

Comment: Maybe both? Based on my observations first I guess.. because I don't know the the theoretical density of the population ( what if it has a normal distribution? )...

Answer (score 0):

Since the distribution of sums of variables is given by [convolutions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution_of_probability_distributions), you could do an approximation to the convolutions using FFTs using small enough sampling windows based on the gaps between your population values.

If k is large, you can use the central limit theorem to approximate:

sqrt(k)(sum_k(x_k)/k - population-mean)/population_stdev as Normal(0,1).
which makes it very easy to evaluate:

P(sum_k(x_k)/k< Val) = P( sqrt(k)(sum_k(x_k)/k - population_mean)/population_stdev<sqrt(k)(Val-population_mean/population_stdev)

= Phi(sqrt(k)(Val-population_mean)/population_stdev) where [Phi is the standard normal CDF.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Cumulative_distribution_functions)